# How to get a full span of the start and end of a week

Tags: php, datetime, range

I was trying to find a simple solution to getting a date range, specifically the start of a week to the end of a week.

I found a few solutions here which were very complicated.  I wanted a two line solution.
I thought my solution might help someone so I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new \DateTime(/* any point in time and space */);

$week_start = new \DateTime(sprintf('%s today this week',           $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
$week_end   = new \DateTime(sprintf('%s today next week -1 second', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

echo sprintf('%s -> %s', $week_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $week_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

A commonly overlooked feature of PHP's english to date expressions is how you can inherit words and dates from each other in what might appear to be conflicting expressions.

However you can add multiple expressions, and each one will inherit from the last.
So by adding a specific date and formatting it at the start of the expression, you can add `today` to get the start of that date.

After that `this week` to get the start of the week, inherits from the same, plus `today`, so the start of `this week` becomes the start of `that week`.

For the end date, I used the `next week` on the same principle, but applied `-1 second` afterwards, which gives us the first and last seconds of the week.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to the same result:-

```
$sunday = 0;
$monday = 1;
$date = new \DateTime(/* any point in time and space */);

$weekStart = (new \DateTime())->setISODate((int)$date->format('o'), (int)$date->format('W'), $monday)->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$weekEnd = (new \DateTime())->setISODate((int)$date->format('o'), (int)$date->format('W') + 1, $sunday)->setTime(23, 59, 59);

echo sprintf('%s -> %s', $weekStart->format('Y m d H:i:s'), $weekEnd->format('Y m d H:i:s'));
```

Personally, I prefer this type of method to passing a 'natural language' type string which, to me, has ambiguous meaning.